# About queue and standard deviation

Tags: algorithm

I'm not sure where should this problem goes as it sounds mathematical too, but due to programming nature, I still decide to put it here.

I have a queue of constant size which keeps loading data to back and poping data from front (keeping the size at constant), and **I want the standard deviation (sigma) from the queue**. I know a for loop implementation is easy job for this but the time grows quite badly when the size goes large. Is there a better implementation?

Comment: From the current state of queue or all-time?

Comment: I'm analyzing data by taking samples, it seems work efficiently so far for taking samples daily,hourly & minutely; but when it comes to secondly, overwhelmed. Since together Im also calculating mean of the data by adding back minus front with a speed of constant time, I'm thinking whether similar methodology exist for standard deviation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your efficient method for the mean also for the standard deviation because of the formula `std dev = sqrt(E(x^2)-E(x)^2)` [(proof on wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Definition_of_population_values).

In other words, keep track of the sum of the squares of your values (e.g. in variable sum_of_squares), and keep track of the sum of the values (e.g. in variable sum_of_values).  In both cases you can update the variable in O(1) by adding one value and taking away an old value.

Then the standard deviation can be computed as:

```
mean = sum_of_values/n
std_dev = sqrt( sum_of_squares/n - mean*mean )
```

Comment: Exactly the solution I was in the middle of typing up! +1

Comment: If the mean of the data is large compared with the noise there is a danger that sum_of_squares/n - mean*mean could be negative due to rounding error; in any case you will loose precision.

Comment: Here is a variation that copes with the negative issue: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/811/determining-the-mean-and-standard-deviation-in-real-time

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by maintaining 3 variables: N the number, M the mean and V the variance, each of  of the elements in the queue.

If you start with an empty queue, N=0, M=0.0 and V=0.0.

To add element x to the queue (dx and f are locals)

```
N += 1;
f = 1.0/N;
dx = x - M;
M += f*dx;
V = (1.0-f)*(V+f*dx*dx);
```

To remove element x from the queue

```
N -= 1
if ( N == 0)
{   M = 0.0; V= 0.0;
}
else
{   f = 1.0/N;
    dx = x - M;
    M -= f*dx;
    V = (1.0+f)*(V - f*dx*dx);
}
```